# Rendering tags that were input into textarea with string.replace

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'd like a user to be able to use basic html tags within a textarea and render those tags rather than displaying them as text after the user submits the form. For example, if the users enters

```
<i>Hi there</i>
```

and then they click submit, the next page will display their entry into the textarea. What they will see on the next page is Hi there in italics. I've tried this code, but it doesn't seem to work.

```
$('.blogbody').each(function() {
  var string = $(this).html();  
  $(this).html(string.replace('<i>', '<i>'));   
  });
```

Thanks!

Comment: I think it's impossible to do that with a `<textarea>`. The HTML `<textarea>` element represents a multi-line **plain-text** editing control. [From MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/textarea)

Comment: Didn't notice that I deleted the original comment.

Comment: I should clarify. I'm not trying to render stylized text inside a text area. User submits textarea form. I parse out the tags from the content and take them to another page where what they input into the textarea is displayed in a <div> and that is where the style is applied.

Comment: `string.replace('<i>', '<i>')` - and that is supposed to achieve what exactly?

Comment: Well, then what's really bothering you? Any error message?

Comment: Nope, no error message. I just found out the problem. Django doesn't allow you to render html from user submitted info.

Comment: CBroe: I was hoping that it would take plain text of <i> and replace with html of <i>.